# Algorithm: Picking several items of different weights so that the sum of them remains as close to some value as possible

Tags: algorithm, math, distribution

I have 3 folders, each of them contains different number of files.

Folder_#1: audio files with the maximum duration 170 ms.

Folder_#2: audio files with the min duration 170 ms and max duration 460 ms.

Folder_#3: audio files with the minimum duration 460 ms.

Now I need to pick files from three of them so that the sum of their duration would make up 720 ms, or as close as possible to it.

There is a requirement that all audio files from 3 folders should be used.

What is a good algorithm for this?

Comment: This is a variant of the knapsack problem. It's NP hard, but you should be able to search for solutions now you know the name of it.

Comment: How many files do you have in each? Easy answer: check all combinations with 3 nested for loops.

Comment: How many times are you allowed to use a single file?

Comment: File duration: is it always an integer?

Comment: @STF each file is allowed to be used oly once. and yes, it's always an integer

Comment: @OneLyner it's never a fixed amount of files inside of folders

Comment: @PaulHankin sorry, what does NP hard mean? And thanks for an insight!

Comment: There's plenty of material online about what NP hard is.

Answer (score 0):

Try brute force, computers are fast:
(this is just pseudocode)

```
best = float("inf")
res = None
for f1 in Folder_1:
    for f2 in Folder_2:
        for f3 in Folder_3:
            dist = abs(f1.size + f2.size + f3.size - 720)
            if dist < best:
                best = dist
                res = (f1, f2, f3)
return res
```

If *and only if* that's not fast enough, try being smart.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved using very simple dynamic programming. Try to allocate an array of `720+170` cells (corresponding to the total combined file duration), then iterate over the files in each folder (in order) and mark the cells which can be reached. If a cell can be reached using the files from all 3 folders, it is a candidate solution. The closest one to `720` wins.